# When do *connected* smooth representatives of $n[C] \in H_2(S,\mathbb{Z})$ exist?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $S$ be a complex surface, and let $[C] \in H_2(S,\mathbb{Z})$ be the homology class of a complex curve $C$ on $S$.

I am wondering when there will exist a smooth *connected* representative of the class $n[C]$ for $n>1$. (It is known that there always exists a smooth representative.)

As examples: in $\mathbb{P}^2$ there are connected smooth representatives of $n[H]$ where $H$ is the hyperplane class, while this is not the case for $n[H_1]$ in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ where $H_1$ is the hyperplane class of one of the $\mathbb{P}^1$s. We can note the self-intersections differ in the two cases - $[H]\cdot[H]=1$ while $[H_1]\cdot[H_1]=0$ - and perhaps this is important. Any answer, hint, or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Bertini tells you that if $C$ is ample, then for all large $n$, such representatives exist (contrast the two examples you wrote).